# Shell Script - CSV file change value of n'th column if column b contains the serach string

Tags: bash, shell, csv, awk, sed

There are a lot of questions on data processing on a CSV file. But all are specific.

I have comma separated CSV file. I have already done required operations but there is one step which i am still stuck at.

Please note i am looking to make this change using Shell Script. 'AWK' or 'SED' might help me but i lack the knowledge of correct syntax for this.

Input:

```
Index,SrNo,Name,Desc,Target,Strength
1,125,RX,Big,NULL,236
2,246,DMT,Med,NULL,548
3,425,VT,SML,NULL,461
4,512,RX,Big,NULL,415
5,951,VT,SML,NULL,243
6,426,DMT,Med,NULL,412
```

I want to change the value of column 'Target' from NULL to 'ACTIVE' if The column 'NAME' is either 'RX' or 'DMT'.

Below is the expected output.

```
Index,SrNo,Name,Desc,Target,Strength
1,125,RX,Big,Active,236
2,246,DMT,Med,Active,548
3,425,VT,SML,NULL,461
4,512,RX,Big,Active,415
5,951,VT,SML,NULL,243
6,426,DMT,Med,Active,412
```

Comment: Is input comma separated (not shown in sample data)?

Comment: thaks anubhava, I edited the request to show it in correct format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your input is comma delimited as the question says, you can use this awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} $3 ~ /^(RX|DMT)$/{$5 = "ACTIVE"} 1' file.csv

Index,SrNo,Name,Desc,Target,Strength
1,125,RX,Big,Active,236
2,246,DMT,Med,Active,548
3,425,VT,SML,NULL,461
4,512,RX,Big,Active,415
5,951,VT,SML,NULL,243
6,426,DMT,Med,Active,412
```

To get formatted output use `column`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} $3 ~ /^(RX|DMT)$/{$5 = "ACTIVE"} 1' file.csv  |
column -s, -t

Index  SrNo  Name  Desc  Target  Strength
1      125   RX    Big   Active  236
2      246   DMT   Med   Active  548
3      425   VT    SML   NULL    461
4      512   RX    Big   Active  415
5      951   VT    SML   NULL    243
6      426   DMT   Med   Active  412
```

Comment: Thank you anubhav. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Hi Anubhav, with the same requirement as above can we add something like this. 
If the selection column value which is 'Name' here matches then change the data for more columns than one.
E.g.
If 'Name' is 'RX|DMT' then 'Target' to be set as 'Active' and 'Desc' to be changed as 'Edited'

Comment: Yes that will be: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} $3 ~ /^(RX|DMT)$/{$4 = "Edited"; $5 = "Active"} 1' file.csv`